# How to write test class for below controller?

Tags: unit-test

public class Invoice {
string ids;
private final Invoice_Master__c Invo;
public List ListItems {get; set;}
public Invoice(ApexPages.StandardController Controller){

```
    Invoice_Master__c Invo1 = (Invoice_Master__c)Controller.getRecord();
    ids = Invo1.id;
    system.debug('ids=====>'+ids);
    this.invo =[Select id,Name,Total_Amount__c,Total_CGST__c,Total_SGST__c,Total_IGST__c,Total_tax_inclusive_amount__c,Total_GST__c,(Select id,Name,CGST_Amount__c,SGST_Amount__c,IGST_Amount__c,Amount__c,Product__r.Name From Invoice_Line_Items__r) From Invoice_Master__c where Id =:Invo1.Id];
    
}

public List<ItemWrapper> getItems() {
    String sAmt = '', sName ='', sLast='';
    ListItems = new List<ItemWrapper>();
    for(Invoice_Line_Item__c i:this.invo.Invoice_Line_Items__r){
        system.debug('i======>'+i);
        Decimal dAmt = i.Amount__c;
        sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
        sName = i.Product__r.Name;
        ListItems.add(new ItemWrapper(sName, sAmt));
        system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    }
    return ListItems;
}

//Wrapper Class
public class ItemWrapper {
    public String ItmName{get; set;}
    public String sItemAmt{get; set;}
    public ItemWrapper(String ItemName, String sAmt) {
        this.ItmName = ItemName;
        this.sItemAmt = sAmt;
    }
}

public String getTotalAmt() {
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    Decimal dAmt = Invo.Total_Amount__c;
    sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
    system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    return sAmt;
}
public String getCGST() {
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    
    Decimal dAmt = Invo.Total_CGST__c;
    
    sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
    system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    return sAmt;
    
}
public String getSGST() {
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    
    Decimal dAmt = Invo.Total_SGST__c;
    
    sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
    system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    return sAmt;
    
}

public String getIGST() {
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    
    Decimal dAmt = Invo.Total_IGST__c;
    
    sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
    system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    return sAmt;
    
}

public String getGST() {
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    
    Decimal dAmt = Invo.Total_GST__c;
    
    sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
    system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    return sAmt;
    
}


public String getSubtotal() {
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    
    Decimal dAmt = Invo.Total_tax_inclusive_amount__c;
    
    sAmt = FormulateAmountInString(dAmt);
    system.debug('sAmt======>'+sAmt);
    return sAmt;
    
}


public string FormulateAmountInString(Decimal dAmt) {
    
    String sAmt = '', sTemp ='', sLast='';
    If(dAmt > 1000) {
        sAmt = String.valueOf(dAmt);
        sLast = sAmt.right(6);
        sTemp = sAmt.left(sAmt.length() - 6);
        if(sTemp.length() > 2) {
            while( sTemp.length()/2 > 0) {
                sLast = sTemp.right(2)+ ',' + sLast;
                sTemp = sTemp.Left(sTemp.length() -2);
            }
        }
        if(sTemp != '') {
            sAmt = sTemp + ',' + sLast;
        }
    } else {
        sAmt = String.valueOf(dAmt);
    }
    return sAmt;
    
}
```

}

---

I already create test class i need to know to write test class for wrapper class

```
@istest
public class Invoicetest {
    Private static testMethod void testMethod1(){
        
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test';
        insert acc;
        
        Invoice_Master__c Inv = new Invoice_Master__c();
        Inv.Account__c = acc.Id;
        insert Inv;
        
        product2 pro = new Product2();
        pro.Name = 'Test';
        insert pro;
        
        Invoice_Line_Item__c Invoice = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
        Invoice.Invoice__c = Inv.Id;
        Invoice.Product__c = Pro.Id;
        Invoice.Quantity__c = 10;
        Invoice.UnitPrice__c = 1000.00;
        Invoice.Months__c = 2.00;
        insert Invoice;
   
        Test.startTest();
         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(Inv);
         ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(Invoice.Id));
         Invoice invCtrl = new Invoice(sc);
       //  invCtrl.invo = Inv;
        Test.stopTest();
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an apex class with this kind of skeleton :

```
@isTest
public class Invoice_Test {
    static testMethod void test1(){
         Invoice_Master__c im = new Invoice_Master__c (
             Name = 'Invoice test',
             Total_Amount__c = 123
              ...
             etc
         );
         insert im;
    }
}
```

Basically test classes is all about **inserting/updating/deleting** dummy data into the system to test your apex code you created. This alone will help cover most of the test coverage. Then if it still below 75% call your methods in your apex classes.

If you want to make it even more robust, then you have to think how to test it using System.AssertEquals().

Comment: This is frankly bad advice and factually incorrect. Unit tests are not all about DML, calling random Apex code for coverage is a bad practice, and unit tests without assertions have very little value.

Comment: How is that factually incorrect? Every official example help/trailhead involve DMLs in apex test classes https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_example.htm. 
And when you are strapped for time taking over old developers code and the current users in production require a change on the VF/ Aura pages you most likely won't have time to write assertions to deploy to production.